# Querying the React root element in React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my React component, a `div` with the id `#keys` goes from `display: none` to `display: flex` when you press `/` while focusing on `document`.

I wrote a test for that using Jest and React Testing Library:

**App.tsx:**

```
return (
    <div id="keys" style={{ display: isInputFocused ? 'flex' : 'none' }}>
        <input
            type="text"
            ref={inputRef}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={handleInputBlur}
            value={inputValue}
        />
        <!-- more elements -->
    </div>
);
```

**App.test.tsx:**

```
test('`input` is visible after pressing `/`', () => {
    render(<App />);
    fireEvent.keyDown(document, { key: '/' });

    const input = screen.getByRole('textbox', { hidden: true });

    expect(input).toBeVisible();
});
```

As you can see, in my test, I'm querying the `input` inside `#keys` instead of `#keys`. If I want to query `#keys` in the RTL way, I have to add `role` or `data-testid` to `#keys`.

Question 1: That's the best way to query `#keys`? So that I'm testing the visibility of `#keys` instead of the `input` inside it? (Without having to add `role` or `data-testid` to it?)

Question 2: Or maybe according to RTL's philosophy, I'm not supposed to be testing `#keys` but the `input` inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You can still use "normal" dom queries in RTL although it is not recommended as mentioned in the **[docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#manual-queries)**:

```
const { container } = render(<MyComponent />)
const keys = container.querySelector('#keys');
```

You can also use `parentElement` or `parentNode` but I think that falls under the same category as above

```
const keys = screen.getByRole('textbox').parentElement;
```

2 - Like you suspected, RTL's philosophy is querying and testing elements that are visible and matter to the users of your app which means that if you are unable to query those elements with **[high priority queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority)** you either don't need to test them or you need to improve their accessibility:

RTL docs (from the first link I shared)

> Note that using this as an escape hatch to query by class or id is not recommended because they are invisible to the user.

Your `keys` element is just a container and doesn't have any significance to the end user, on the other hand the inputs inside of it are the elements the user is going to be interacting with, which means they should be the ones being tested for behavior and visibility.